# Test class failing for simple default lookup value trigger

Tags: apex, unit-test, lookup

I'm having trouble with what should be a simple test class for a simple trigger.

The trigger inserts the ID of an account named Retail into a lookup field on the opportunity named `Project__c` if that field is blank. The trigger works but the test class fails.

The error I'm getting is:-->`System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 0011100000ArLgYAAV, Actual: null`

So, my test isn't updating the ID although in real application the ID is updated?

If anyone can let me know what I've done wrong it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

**Trigger**

```
trigger AutoRetail on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {

Account RetailAccount = [
    Select Id
    From Account
    Where Name = 'Retail'
];

for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {

        if(o.Project__c == Null){

o.Project__c = RetailAccount.Id;
```

**Test Class**

```
@IsTest
private class AutoRetail_Test {

static testMethod void AutoRetail() {

    // Create an Account
    Account a = new account();
    a.Name = 'Test Account';
    insert a;

    // Create a 'Retail' Account
    Account r = new account();
    r.Name = 'Retail';
    insert r;

    // Create an Opportunity
    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
    opp.Name = 'TestOppFromTestClass' ;
    opp.StageName = 'Stage 1 - Reviewing Information' ;
    opp.CloseDate = Date.Today() ;
    opp.Accountid = a.id;
    insert opp ;


    // Query Success

    system.AssertEquals(r.id, opp.Project__c);


}

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to query result before the assertion.

For example:

```
List<Opportunity> Opp=[Select Project__c FROM Opportunity WHERE ID =:opp.id];

system.AssertEquals(r.id,Opp[0].Project__c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to retrieve the inserted opportunity again and then do the assertion against that.
`opp = [SELECT Name, Project__c FROM Opportunity WHERE ID =: opp.Id];
System.AssertEquals(r.id, opp[0].Project__c);`