# code coverage on triggers

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

Please help me, its covering only 45%, i want to cover 100%. How will we do it?

```
trigger DiseasesCountForDivisions on account (after insert,after update,after delete) {

    private  Set<Id>  DivisionIdSet = new Set<Id>();

  System.debug('###1');
    if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate){

        for(account accObj : Trigger.new){
            DivisionIdSet.add(accObj.division__c);
        }
    }

    System.debug('####2'+DivisionIdSet);
    if (Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isDelete) {

        for(account accObj : Trigger.old){

            DivisionIdSet.add(accObj.division__c);
        }
    }
 System.debug('####3');
    Double cancerCount = 0;
    Double ThalassemiaCount = 0;
    Double HIVCount = 0;
    Double JuvenileCount = 0;
    Double CardiacCount = 0;
    Double OthersCount = 0;

List<division__c> listofdivision = new List<division__c>();

  listofdivision =  [Select Id,(Select ID, Cancer__c, Cardiac__c, Juvenile__c, Others__c, HIV__c, Thalassemia__c FROM Hospitals__r) from Division__c WHERE ID IN :DivisionIdSet];  
    system.debug('$$'+listofdivision);
    for(Division__c eachdivision : listofdivision){
       List<Account> listOfHosp = eachdivision.Hospitals__r;
        for(Account eachHospital : listOfHosp){

            System.debug('###CCVar:'+cancerCount);
            System.debug('###CCObjID:'+eachHospital.Id);
            System.debug('###CCObj:'+eachHospital.Cancer__c);

            if(eachHospital.Cancer__c!=null){
                cancerCount = cancerCount+eachHospital.Cancer__c;
            }

              if(eachHospital.Thalassemia__c!=null){
                ThalassemiaCount= ThalassemiaCount+eachHospital.Thalassemia__c;
            }

              if(eachHospital.Juvenile__c!=null){
                JuvenileCount= JuvenileCount+eachHospital.Juvenile__c;
            }

              if(eachHospital.Cardiac__c!=null){
                CardiacCount= CardiacCount+eachHospital.Cardiac__c;
            }

              if(eachHospital.HIV__c!=null){
                HIVCount= HIVCount+eachHospital.HIV__c;
            }

              if(eachHospital.Others__c!=null){
                OthersCount= OthersCount+eachHospital.Others__c;
            }                      
        }

        eachdivision.cancer__c=cancerCount;
        eachdivision.Thalassemia__c=ThalassemiaCount ;
        eachdivision.Juvenile__c=JuvenileCount;
        eachdivision.Cardiac__c=CardiacCount;
        eachdivision.HIV__c=HIVCount;
        eachdivision.Others__c=OthersCount;                        
    }

    Update listofdivision;
    System.debug('####Total Cancer Count:'+cancerCount);

    }
```

Test Class :

```
@isTest 
private class TestCountDiseases {
    static testMethod void validateCountDiseases() {
      account a = new account();
      a.division__c = 'Bangalore';
       a.name = 'NIMS';
       a.Cancer__c =10;
       a.Cardiac__c = 20;
       a.Juvenile__c = 30;
       a.Others__c = 40;
       a.HIV__c = 50;
       a.Thalassemia__c = 60;
       insert a;
       a =  [Select name, Cancer__c, Cardiac__c, Juvenile__c, Others__c, HIV__c, Thalassemia__c from account WHERE ID =:a.ID];
       System.assertEquals(10, a.Cancer__c);
       a.cancer__c=20;

       update a;                             
    }
}
```

Comment: `division__c` in your account object, is it a lookup field or text field? as per your trigger it looks like a lookup where in your test class it looks like a text field

Comment: Your test case needs to also insert at least one Division__c object as a lot of the trigger code is in a loop over those objects. Ensure its relationship to the Account is correctly setup too.

Comment: Division__c is  a lookup field in account object, please tell me how to declare?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test class failing for simple default lookup value trigger](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29990/test-class-failing-for-simple-default-lookup-value-trigger)

Comment: Not understand, take my program and please explain me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Division__c is a custom object that your trigger queries and its ID value is stored in a field on Account probably called Hospital__c but you would need to check that. So to get the main body of your loop to run you need to setup a Division__c object to in your test.

The code to do that would be:

```
static testMethod void validateCountDiseases() {
    Division__c d = new Division__c();
    insert d;
    account a = new account();
    // Check the name of this field that references the Division__c
    a.Hospital__c = d.Id;
    ...
}
```